# Deployment of Base-Node via iSCSI in Server 2012R2 HPC cluster fails (can not join domain)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, deployment, iscsi, hpc

We are currently evaluating Server 2012R2 with HPC Pack for an upcoming project.

Sadly we are stuck at deploying the base node. The node boots via PXE (iPXE) and connects to iSCSI, installs Windows but then seems unable to join the domain.

Once the deployment fails the node remains as a windows installed on an iSCSI drive.

We are then able to manually join the domain and log in with a domain user.
We can pink the server by both IPs.
Ping to cluster.local or HEAD-NODE.cluster.local get resolved to the IP of the servers NIc for the private network (.10.1)

Running the Deployment: Binding Order Test yields only:

> **Warning:** The Enterprise network is not configured first in the binding order on default gateways. This might cause problems communicating with Active Directory Domain Services.

---

**Deployment: Binding Order Test**

```
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Network "Private" description: Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection #2
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Network interface type: Ethernet
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Address: 192.168.10.1
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Network "Enterprise" description: Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Network interface type: Ethernet
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Address: 192.168.178.5
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Microsoft HPC Diagnostic Test Host.
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Creating test instances from: PDCNet.dll:Microsoft.Hpc.Diagnostics.Tests.BindingOrder.
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Verbose] Failed to load assembly OriginalPath: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///\\HEAD-NODE\Diagnostics\1125\PDCNet.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.Hpc.Diagnostics.TestHost.Program.CreateTestInstance(String assemblyName, String className)
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Verbose] Retrying from location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin\PDCNet.dll
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Verbose] Failed to load assembly EXEPath: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin\PDCNet.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.Hpc.Diagnostics.TestHost.Program.CreateTestInstance(String assemblyName, String className)
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Verbose] Retrying from location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin\DiagTests\PDCNet.dll
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Verbose] Doing test on test type: Microsoft.Hpc.Diagnostics.Tests.BindingOrder.
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Got domain controller name: HEAD-NODE.cluster.local
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Resolved IP address for DC. Got 4 IP addessses.
14-7-2015 20:20:32 [Information] Routing to address: 192.168.10.1.
```

So we looked into that. However, it all seems to be fine.
Changing the binding order in the advanced settings resolved neither the test nor the actual deployment.

---

**NIC settings**

***Enterprise***

```
Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection
cluster.local
IPv6 - disabled
IPv4
192.168.178.5
255.255.255.0
192.168.178.1
DNS
212.54.40.25
192.168.178.1
QoS Packed Scheduler - enabled
Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver - enabled
Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder - enabled
```

***Private***

```
Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection #2
cluster.local
IPv6 - disabled
IPv4
192.168.10.1
255.255.255.0
no default gateway
DNS
127.0.0.1
QoS Packed Scheduler - enabled
Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver - enabled
Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder - enabled
```

---

**Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections\Advanced\Advanced Settings\Adapter and Bindings\Connections**

```
Enterprise
Private
[Remote Access connections]
```

---

**Console:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>wmic nicconfig get Description,SettingID
Description                                  SettingID
WAN Miniport (L2TP)                          {06E102F9-E21B-4CEF-B0CA-64F4829A9A7C}
WAN Miniport (SSTP)                          {577B93D0-F1FD-4C7B-B41E-53B4BA94A579}
WAN Miniport (IKEv2)                         {1AF75D00-449A-4CC1-9ED1-FB440172AED2}
WAN Miniport (PPTP)                          {A235D4B4-600A-4FFA-8E12-9BA09E6DAF65}
WAN Miniport (PPPOE)                         {4E1B3D6C-934D-43DF-9301-DA9CC9E8A407}
WAN Miniport (IP)                            {3F6E7537-F2F8-4AEA-8B72-B7A4D7298D4E}
WAN Miniport (IPv6)                          {041B181E-0469-42FD-B6B4-F32842B6495B}
WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)               {C9875A41-724D-4987-9F2D-A41F8AE84E2F}
Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter       {C7568B63-C424-48B3-AB9B-6D1F004D5AFC}
RAS Async Adapter                            {D0FA3B2F-90BF-4A07-83E3-81165D8B28EF}
Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection     {5BC77C5E-0E79-4C01-9C9A-A28CFA94F898}
Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection #2  {0260FC73-5ABF-4814-AB52-D16DEFFA4875}
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                     {266E5AE1-245A-4D47-9E73-F37AFFE434A4}
Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter           {D9B3F7F2-A448-4513-BD48-A1B215C54DCF}
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                     {40F0B15B-06DA-4E06-A43C-89AD60918DEC}
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                     {DFA7713A-B5DC-4144-BB90-3A546C0EE42E}
Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter   {341D1797-925C-49CC-9C24-50AFC0F0C105}
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                     {8BE73B7C-14DE-4E5C-92FA-1F6C8CF0FBF6}
Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             {A71BD6F0-072F-4C9A-8963-780EE41C896C}
```

---

**Registry:** [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage]

```
\Device\{5BC77C5E-0E79-4C01-9C9A-A28CFA94F898}
\Device\{A71BD6F0-072F-4C9A-8963-780EE41C896C}
\Device\{341D1797-925C-49CC-9C24-50AFC0F0C105}
\Device\{0260FC73-5ABF-4814-AB52-D16DEFFA4875}
\Device\{C7568B63-C424-48B3-AB9B-6D1F004D5AFC}
```

---

**Hardware:**

***Server***

```
ASRock J1900D2Y, 16 GB, 3TB HDD
Windows Server 2012R2 Evaluation
Roles: AD DS, DHCP (for Private), DNS (for Private), WDS, HPC Cluster HEAD-NODE
LAN1: Enterprise, 192.168.178.5 (static)
LAN2: Private, 192.168.10.1 (static)
IPMI: 192.168.178.6 (static), 192.168.178.28 (DHCP)
```

***Base-NODE***

```
ASRock Q1900TM-ITX, 4 GB, no HDD
Windows 8.1 Embedded
(the important thing is Quick-Sync)
LAN: Private, 192.168.10.6 (DHCP)
```

The cluster nodes are meant to encode parts of a large video and eventually join the parts.
So the hardware requirements for our nodes are: Intel Quick-Sync, low power consumption, small form factor.

---

**Deployment log:**

```
Time    Message
10-7-2015 23:57:18  Reverted
10-7-2015 23:57:17  Disassociating template from node CLUSTER\ENCODER1000
10-7-2015 23:57:17  The operation failed due to errors during execution.
10-7-2015 23:57:17  The operation failed and will not be retried.
10-7-2015 23:57:17  The operation failed due to errors during execution.
10-7-2015 23:57:17  The operation failed and will not be retried.
10-7-2015 23:57:17  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:57:05  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:57:03  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:56:51  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:56:49  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:56:37  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:56:35  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:56:23  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:56:21  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:56:09  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:56:07  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:55:55  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:55:53  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:55:41  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:55:39  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:55:27  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:55:25  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:55:13  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:55:10  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:54:58  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:54:56  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:54:44  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:54:42  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:54:30  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:54:28  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:54:16  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:54:14  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:54:02  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:54:00  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:53:48  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:53:46  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:53:34  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:53:32  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:53:20  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:53:18  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:53:06  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:53:04  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:52:52  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:52:50  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:52:38  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:52:36  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:52:24  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:52:22  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:52:10  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:52:08  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:51:55  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:51:53  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:51:41  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:51:39  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:51:27  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:51:25  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:51:13  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:51:11  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:50:59  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:50:57  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:50:45  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:50:43  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:50:31  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:50:29  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:50:17  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:50:15  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:50:03  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:50:01  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:49:49  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:49:47  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:49:35  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:49:33  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:49:21  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:49:19  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:49:06  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:49:04  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:48:52  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:48:50  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:48:38  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:48:36  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:48:24  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:48:22  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:48:10  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:48:08  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:47:56  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:47:54  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:47:42  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:47:40  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:47:28  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:47:26  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:47:14  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:47:12  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:47:00  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:46:58  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:46:46  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:46:44  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:46:32  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:46:30  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:46:18  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:46:16  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:46:04  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:46:02  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:45:50  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:45:48  Exit code 1: Incorrect function
10-7-2015 23:45:45  Joining domain: cluster.local
10-7-2015 23:45:38  Disabling Windows Recovery Mode (optimization for iSCSI-boot scenario)
10-7-2015 23:45:36  Waiting for iSCSI boot nodes to boot and start Windows setup
10-7-2015 23:32:48  Sending PXE command to boot node to the current OS
10-7-2015 23:32:44  Sending PXE command to boot node to the current OS
10-7-2015 23:29:19  Sending PXE command to boot node to the current OS
10-7-2015 23:29:15  Sending PXE command to boot node to the current OS
10-7-2015 23:06:48  Installing Windows (Expected time: 30 minutes)
10-7-2015 23:06:43  Customizing the Windows unattended installation script
10-7-2015 23:06:37  Cleaning up WIM file
10-7-2015 23:02:16  Extracting WIM C:\Win8.1 embedded industry.WIM to C:\Install
10-7-2015 23:02:11  Creating local directory for install media
10-7-2015 22:58:17  Copying: Images\Win8.1 embedded industry.WIM
10-7-2015 22:57:53  Configuring disk partitions
10-7-2015 22:57:48  Copying: config\diskpart.txt
10-7-2015 22:57:42  Mounting the installation shared folder on the head node
10-7-2015 22:54:32  Sending PXE command to boot node to WINPE (Expected boot time: 5-15 minutes)
10-7-2015 22:54:22  Sending PXE command to boot node to WINPE (Expected boot time: 5-15 minutes)
10-7-2015 22:54:17  Waiting for node to boot into WINPE
10-7-2015 22:54:17  Initiating configuration operations for template: Default Base Template
10-7-2015 22:54:17  Computer account ENCODER1000 created
10-7-2015 22:54:17  The computer account ENCODER1000 does not exist; creating a new account in Active Directory.
10-7-2015 22:54:17  Searching for an existing account in Active Directory
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Connecting to domain controller: cluster.local
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Initiating provisioning operations for template: Default Base Template
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Creating DHCP reservation 192.168.10.6 on scope 192.168.10.0
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Setting DHCP option 17 to iscsi:192.168.10.1::::iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:head-node-encoder1000-base-target
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Setting DHCP option 12 to encoder1000
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Setting DHCP option 203 to iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:encoder1000.cluster.local
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Creating a reservation for network adapter: D0509947B72C
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Mapping successful
10-7-2015 22:54:16  Mapping client [iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:encoder1000.cluster.local] to target LUN [ENCODER1000-BASE] on storage array [127.0.0.1]
10-7-2015 22:54:15  Remote disk disconnected
10-7-2015 22:53:44  Disconnecting remote disk
10-7-2015 22:53:34  Configuring bootloader
10-7-2015 22:53:31  Copying WinPE files
10-7-2015 22:53:29  Placing bootloader
10-7-2015 22:53:29  Mount successful at: C:\Windows\TEMP\uhusex01.bsn
10-7-2015 22:53:16  Connection established, mounting disk
10-7-2015 22:53:15  Connecting to iSCSI target: 192.168.10.1 / iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:head-node-encoder1000-base-target
10-7-2015 22:53:15  Mapping successful
10-7-2015 22:53:14  Mapping client [iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:HEAD-NODE.cluster.local] to target LUN [ENCODER1000-BASE] on storage array [127.0.0.1]
10-7-2015 22:53:14  Base LUN creation complete
10-7-2015 22:53:14  Creation successful
10-7-2015 22:53:13  Creating base LUN "ENCODER1000-BASE"
10-7-2015 22:53:12  Setting boot-initiator information
10-7-2015 22:53:12  Associating template Default Base Template with node CLUSTER\ENCODER1000
10-7-2015 22:53:12  Moving node CLUSTER\ENCODER1000 from state Unknown to state Provisioning
10-7-2015 22:53:11  Assigning template Default Base Template to node ENCODER1000
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Can some one please point us in the right direction?
2. <del>Why does the test claim the binding order is off, while it seems to be ok?</del> seems its a problem between the hardware and windows
3. <del>How can I resolve the binding order and make the test pass?</del> switch the NICs
4. <del>Is that even the real problem?</del> apparently not
5. If not how could I narrow it down or can some one directly tell what the problem is?

We are running out of ideas on what to try.

---

**Update 1:**

We switched the two NIC connectors around (cables, settings, binding order). Hard to believe but that solved the test. Sadly it did not solve the actual problem. Joining the domain (during deployment) still fails, while we can join it by hand (which will cancel the deployment).

Comment: While this may seem like a very subjective response if the highest possible performance is the end goal Windows Server is a less than ideal choice for cluster management.  [there is currently a grand total of 1](http://www.top500.org/statistics/details/osfam/2) system on the top500 list that uses Windows.  There is a good reason that the other 499 systems chose a different operating system to base their clusters on, 486 chose Linux as of last count.  There are a variety of reference designs available for building Linux clusters if that is an option

Comment: @Matt I am aware of that fact, however so far Quick Sync only works on Windows (apart from one very expensive lib). So at least the compute node need to run Windows! Is there a linux based system that could deploy windows compute notes? If yes I would consider it.

Comment: that would seem to complicate things a little bit.  It seems like Quick Sync is a hardware technology so do you mean that the software you use to take advantage of this feature is only usable on Windows systems?

Comment: so far yes - the compute nodes need to run windows, since we want to use [q264](http://www.tetrachromesoftware.com/q264-index.htm) which gains it speed and quality from Intel's Quick Sync, each node will encode a part of a larger video, Quick Sync offers the best compromise between speed, quality and power consumption